# alignment issues with logo design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, alignment

first time posting here. first off wanted to say that I'm very thankful to the community for all of the answers it has provided me with just a simple search.

BUT now I have a question and I have no idea how to specify that in a search engine haha so here goes.

I am trying to create a logo for my future business in graphic design and hopefully much more haha.
It uses a bunch of perfect circles that are scaled based on the Fibonacci ratios. Anyway, I'm trying to align three elements and I'm sure that you guys have a much more precise way of doing this.[image: hopefully, you get the main idea of what I'm trying to do with this zoomed out version]

This is the issue I'm talking about. As you can see the red like does not intersect perfectly in the middle with the two other lines.
[image]

What would be your simplest solution to moving the red circle down only the y axis but with maximum precision? It is already centred to the other objects and the x-axis.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, Illustrator don't have snap to intersection?

Comment: @slebetman it does, quite a few people just dont know how to snap anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Snapping circles can be tricky, but in this case you can use guides.

Switch to *View > Outline* and do like this:

- Create a horizontal guide which snaps to the point where the three circles must intersect: the center of the small circle.
- Create a vertical guide which snaps to the same point.
- Create a horizontal guide which snaps to the intersection between the vertical guide and the largest circle.
- Select the last horizontal guide and the large circle.
- Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag the guide until it snaps to the horizontal guide you created first.

[image]

Comment: Nice.. so I guess there actually *is* a ease to not have guides always locked :)

Comment: @Scott, yeah. I guess you could just use ordinary lines or rectangles as guides for many things, but they don't snap in quite the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Switch to *Outline Mode* (view > outline) and nudge.

My nudge setting (`Keyboard Increment` in *Preferences > General*) is set to `0p0.125` - meaning an 8th of a point. If the nudge is too great at that point, I simply manually move the object.

Illustrator doesn't contain any feature to align the middle of an arc to anything else. There are third party plugs-ins like ColliderScribe from AstuteGraphics.com which will. You might try their free trial.